# implement transition between two pages in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, transition

Am trying to implement a transition between two pages in HTML with this code, my problem is that i dont know which section of the javascript points to the html page, am clicking on the link and getting a blank white screen. Am expecting to see the current page fade out in time out of 500 seconds and then the new page fades in with the same timing, here is the code anyways

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <li class="waves-effect" ><a href="Netbeans_1.html" onclick="transitionToPage('https://www.google.com')">2</a></li>
<script>
window.transitionToPage = function(href) {
    document.querySelector('body').style.opacity = 0
    setTimeout(function() { 
        window.location.href = href
    }, 500)
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    document.querySelector('body').style.opacity = 1
})
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

And then in my css file, i have this

```
body { 
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity .5s;
}
```

The first page fades out very well but the second one is pure white please help...

```js
window.transitionToPage = function(href) {
    document.querySelector('body').style.opacity = 0
    setTimeout(function() { 
        window.location.href = href
    }, 500)
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    document.querySelector('body').style.opacity = 1
})
```

```css
body { 
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity .5s;
}
```

```html
<li class="waves-effect" ><a href="Netbeans_1.html" onclick="transitionToPage('https://www.google.com')">2</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem is that the default behaviour of `<a>` is to redirect to `href` immediately, if you remove it and only call your function in the `onclick` event it works. (I've increased the fade to show better).

```js
window.transitionToPage = function(href) {
    document.querySelector('body').style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function() { 
        window.location.href = href;
    }, 2000);
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    document.querySelector('body').style.opacity = 1;
});
```

```css
body { 
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

```html
<li class="waves-effect" ><a onclick="transitionToPage('https://www.google.com')">open google</a></li>
```

Edit:

If you still want to use the `href` attribute you can override the default behaviour of the `<a>` tag by returning false on the `onclick` event. For example:

```js
window.transitionToPage = function(link) {
    document.querySelector('body').style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function() { 
        window.location.href = link.href;
    }, 2000);
    return false;
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    document.querySelector('body').style.opacity = 1;
});
```

```css
body { 
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

```html
<li class="waves-effect" ><a href="https://www.google.com" onclick="return transitionToPage(this)">open google</a></li>
```

Comment: Can you edit to make the transition slide out current page and slide in new page?

Comment: What do you mean by "slide out" and "slide in"? Moving the page from right to left before the reload? Or just add the transition to the loading page?

Comment: current page slide out towards left, new page slide in from right side

Comment: Please make an attempt first, then if you couldn't achieve the result you wanted post another question describing the problem you're facing. I'll try to help you out if you comment the link of the question here.